# Unexpected behavior using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Hi im trying to rewrite myweb.com/ivan to a simple url.

I got this on .htaccess in my root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/something$ index.php?page=anunciante&anunciante=something [L,NC]
    RewriteRule (.*)/?restaurantes/(.+)?$ index.php?page=anunciante&anunciante=something [L,NC]
```

Yes, both are the same. If i try to enter myurl.com/ivan i get 'Not found',but if i try to enter myurl.com/restaurantes/something i get into index.php with no problem. In my index.php i have this:

```
 print_r($_GET); die();
```

So with myurl.com/restaurantes/something i get:

```
Array ( [page] => anunciante [anunciante] => something )
```

(like expected)
But i dont know why this not work with myurl.com/ivan
I also tried modifying the rule like:

```
  RewriteRule ^/?ivan$ index...
  RewriteRule ^ivan$ index...
  RewriteRule ^/ivan index...
```

All no succed. Also i dont know where is asking for 'favicon.ico'..
And here is the mod_rewrite log:
asking for myurl.com/something
Log: http://pastebin.com/283kq3R8

asking for myurl.com/restaurantes/something
http://pastebin.com/5QcyuAuW

Comment: Please be consistent in using either `ivan` or `something`. Also work on you accept-rate. Thirdly in mod_rewrite url-paths never start with a `/`, so `/something` should be just `something`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted by @Gerben, do not preface your rule with /.
Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ivan$ index.php?page=anunciante&anunciante=ivan [L,NC]
RewriteRule (.*)/?restaurantes/(.+)?$ index.php?page=anunciante&anunciante=something [L,NC]
```

http://myweb.com/ivan
http://myweb.com/restaurantes/something

Comment: btw, why appear 'favicon.ico' on the request?

Comment: Most modern browsers will look for the favicon.ico even though you haven't referenced it in the html. You can 410 it with a mod_rewrite or you could add one.